# Only update external link when open

Tags: excel, excel-formula, reference

I can find a bunch of links trying to do the exact opposite of this. But not this in particular.

I have a main Workbook, Main.xls and it references other workbooks Ref1.xls, Ref2.xls, and Ref3.xls

Now I want to pull information from cell T15 from each of them and tally them in Main. This is really simple when they're open, but as soon as they're closed the cell value automatically changes from `='Ref1.xls'!$T$15` to a file directory like `='C:\Users\Me\Desktop\[Ref1.xls]Ref1'!$T$15`.

I need it explicitly not to do that and am perfectly fine with it just returning a `#Ref` error or something but I can't find a way to keep it from trying to reference the closed file.

Answer (score 0):

## INDIRECT Function

### Formula

```
=INDIRECT("[Ref1.xls]Ref1!$T$15")
```

### Remarks

When the Source Workbook is closed the value will stay 'visible' in the cell until the Target Workbook is calculated when it will show `#REF!`.

When the Target Workbook is saved and closed while the value is still "visible", next time it is opened and Source Workbook isn't open it will show `#REF!`

Comment: Just tried it. When I had the Reference workbook open it displayed as normal but when I closed it the formula changed to a file directory again. On top of it, no matter what I did I could not get the cell to show the vale in the referenced cell, it just stayed on `#Ref!`

Comment: @MiuKujo: Does your **Ref1.xls** workbook even contain the worksheet **Ref1**? Or is it **Sheet1** or something. You cannot use **[Ref1.xls]!$T$15** without the sheet name and you have to use double quotes (**"**) in the **INDIRECT** function.

Comment: @MiuKujo: I've been playing with the settings (properties) in **Option>Calculation**, and similar behavior occurred when **Calculation** was set to **Manual** (Should be **Automatic**), but the formula definitely never changes to 'file directory'. I don't know how it could do so.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to respond. I played with this for a few days and never did get it working. I solved the problem  by having the macro fill in data on a hidden sheet on the `Main.xls` Workbook, and then referenced those fields in the formulae instead.